# Do we need to redo the settings if we deploy live agent to production?

Tags: sandbox, liveagent

I know that we need to change the organisation ID's and chat button ID's if we move the live agent from sand box to production.

Should i need to reconfigure all the settings and buttons in production or how it is ?

Again should i need to set up live agent from the scratch in the production ?

Is it possible to deploy live agent from sandbox to production ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live Agent can be deployed from sandbox to production.  There is support for the following LiveAgent elements in the metadata API:

- [LiveAgentSettings](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_liveagentsettings.htm) - Represents an organization’s Live Agent settings, such as whether or not Live Agent is enabled.
- [LiveAgentConfig](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_livechatagentconfig.htm) - Represents the configuration of an organization’s Live Agent deployment, such as how many chats can be assigned to an agent and whether or not chat sounds are enabled.
- [LiveChatButton](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_livechatbutton.htm) - Represents a Live Agent deployment’s settings for the button that customers click to chat with an agent and the chat window, such as the label that appears on the button and the pre-chat form that appears before a live chat begins.
- [LiveChatDeployment](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_livechatdeployment.htm) - Represents the configuration settings for a specific Live Agent deployment, such as the branding image for the deployment and whether or not chat transcripts are automatically saved.

If you update your deployment or button through a deployment you should update the code snippets in the webpages that use it. This is noted in the documentation for [LiveAgentButton](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_livechatbutton.htm):

> If you update your chat button through the Metadata API, be sure to update all Web pages that use the same chat button code.

And
[LiveAgentDeployment](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_livechatdeployment.htm):

> If you update your deployment through the Metadata API, be sure to update all Web pages that use the same deployment code.

Comment: Thank you Peter for your answer i coded Prechat form from your Blog only. I have one doubt does the liveagent_button_online_xx change in PROD ? Also does the https://x.xxx.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/31.0/deployment.js changes in PROD ? Also also i have used form action in pre chat form in that i have used https://xx.xxxx.salesforceliveagent.com/content/s/chat?language=en_US#deployment_id=xxx&org_id=xx&button_id=xxx&session_id=x-x-x-x-x Does all these ID's changes? In your blog on Live agent in linkToEntity:Contact" value="Case,ContactId" />Can you please explain what is ContactId

Comment: (1): I'm not sure if the JS file changes. I don't have access to a sandbox to test, but you should be able to test pretty easily. (2): The form action will change because it has IDs in it; however, if you use [the JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/peterknolle/8625272) to dynamically create it you don't have to change the pre-chat page. (3): The ContactId links the Case to Contact via the ContactId field on the Case. Hope this helps!